# how to get data by Id and view bag to view MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have View Named Index     i want to pass data get by GuidId. in Model and View Bag ... after enter Id how do this

```
public IActionResult Index()
{

    return View();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GetDS(Guid Id)
{
      var url = string.Empty;           
      url = ApiEndpoint.serviceUrl + ApiEndpoint.GetDS + Id;
      var data = await ApiService.GetAsync<DSModel>(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

      url = ApiEndpoint.serviceUrl + ApiEndpoint.GetDSL + Id;
      var data2 = await ApiService.GetAsyncCollection<DSLDetails>(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
      ViewBag.DSL = data2;
      return View("Index", data);
}
```

html error shows in HTML Side

```
@foreach (var item in @ViewBag.DSL)
{
    <tr>
         <td>
            @item.Name
         </td>
}
```

> ERROR  NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> ```
> AspNetCore.Views_Division_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
> +
>             @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.DSL)
> ```

Comment: You shouldn't use ViewBag. We have strongly typed models for a reason, which any basic ASP.NET MVC tutorial should show how to use.

Comment: Two things: 1st Check if data2 or @ViewBag.DSL is null before using in foreach, 2nd cast your ViewBag data to appropriate type before using it in foreach

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because @ViewBag.DSL is null in foreach loop. Please make sure that you are storing data in viewbag from server side in action menthod. 
And second thing try this code:

```
@if(ViewBag.DSL != null)
{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.DSL)
    {
        <tr>
             <td>
                @item.Name
             </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```